# Unset/Remove relation object from Laravel Eloquent collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've a fetch a Laravel Eloquent collection by:

```
$product = Product::query()->with(['merchant', 'picture'])->where('id', $id)->first();
```

and get the dump of `$product` is

```
Product {
  #casts: ...
  #dates: ...
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:1 [
    "id" => 27
  ]
  #original: ...
  #changes: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:2 [
    "merchant" => Merchant {...}
    "picture" => Picture {...}
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: ...
}
```

I need to unset the relation object `merchant` and `picture` from this collection.

I've tried following options but failed:

```
unset($product['merchant']);
unset($product->merchant);
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your purpose in unsetting those relations?

Comment: I have to tables with the same fields.. So I need to check the different column based on value.
So if the value of foreign key is same then need to unset that relation

Comment: Which tables do you have with same fields? Could you give an example, please?

Comment: What about doing `$product->merchant = null`?

Comment: That should work if I don't want value. But i need to unset the key.

Comment: Why do you call `->with(['merchant', 'picture'])` when you don't need them?

Comment: @HieuLe Because if their foreign key value isn't match then I need to use this value.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In Laravel 5.6.25, you can use `unsetRelation()`:

```php
$product->unsetRelation('merchant')->unsetRelation('picture');
```

Before that:

```php
$relations = $product->getRelations();
unset($relations['merchant'], $relations['picture']);
$product->setRelations($relations);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Thanks

Comment: how can we make it if we need to check in relationship rows if has condition otherwise unset one row in relationship , thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

you can unset it

```
unset($product->merchant);
```

Comment: Did you even read the question?

"I've tried following options but failed:

unset($product['merchant']);
unset($product->merchant);"

Comment: How exactly it did not work for you? Was there any errors?

Answer (score 2):

> I have to tables with the same fields.. So I need to check the
>   different column based on value. So if the value of foreign key is
>   same then need to unset that relation

If you have `merchant` property in the model (`merchant` column in the table) you can get it value using `$product->getOriginal('merchant')` or `$product->getAttribute('merchant')`

Answer (score 1):

Note that I had an issue with `unsetRelation('polymorphicRelation')` and `unsetRelations()` when using a polymorphic relationship (Laravel 10).

I was able to remove "classic" relationships from my hydrated model, but no matter how I tried to remove the morphed relationship, I would always end with it in my serialized object (`toArray()`).

`unsetRelations()` would remove all but my polymorphic one, and `unsetRelation('polymorphicRelation')` did nothing on the polymorphic. But both worked perfectly with a belongsTo relation also eager loaded/hydrated.

I could fix this using:

`$model->unsetRelation('polymorphicRelation')->setHidden(['polymorphicRelation'])->toArray()`. (not sure that the `unsetRelation` is really useful in this case.

The "Before that" option of Jonas Staudenmeir may also work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
withoutEagerLoads()
```

Worked for me here is an eample:

```
$observations = Observation::selectRaw('COUNT(*) as count, DATE(created_at) as date')
        ->whereIn('tenant_id', $tenant_ids)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', $timelines[$request->timeline])
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->withoutEagerLoads()
        ->get();
```