# Appended one accessor but resource has more than one, how is this possible? - Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to use an accessor on a model to return the status whether a relationship exists.

**My User model:**

```php
class User {

  protected $appends = ['has_profile'];
    
  public function profile()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class)
  }

  public function getHasProfileAttribute()
  {
    $exists = $this->profile;

    if($exists){
      return 1;
    }
    else{
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is when the User model is loaded via `User::find(1)->get();`, the `profile` property is also loaded into JSON resource whereas, I only want the `has_profile` attribute in my JSON return. How should I query the relationship existence without loading it, or should I unload the relationship?

**What I Get**

```json
"data": {
        "id": 270,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "mobile_number": "01234567890",
        "created_at": "2021-08-19T06:55:33.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-08-19T06:55:33.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "has_profile": 1,
        "profile": {
                 "id": 1,
                 "details": "Details"
                 }
    }
```

**What I want**

```json
"data": {
        "id": 270,
        "name": "John Doe"
        "mobile_number": "01234567890",
        "created_at": "2021-08-19T06:55:33.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-08-19T06:55:33.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "has_profile": 1
    }
```

## Updated Solution

The problem was `$this->profile` which led to the profile relation being attached. When used as `$this->profile()->get();` or `$this->profile()->first();` it works as **expected**.

Comment: fyi, no need to use `->get()` when using `->find()`, `User::find(1);` will do it

Comment: The `has()` method always returns true even if the relationship doesn't exist. Not sure why. Eg: `$exists = is_null($this->has('profile')->get())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **unset** to remove the attribute **profile**.

```
public function getHasProfileAttribute()
{
    $exists = $this->profile;
    unset($this->profile);
    if($exists){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the unset() works but I came across `$this->unsetRelation($relation)` which works too. Any idea on why does that happen though?

Comment: Does it work?
Ideas you can refer link: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278128/unset-remove-relation-object-from-laravel-eloquent-collection/52278596#52278596)

Comment: Sorry to remove your answer as the correct one, I found the issue and updated another solution for it.

Comment: @PremArumugam
No problem, if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `except()` method from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-except)

```
User::find(1)->get()->except('profile');
```

Maybe you have to change order i can't test right now but it's the idea

Comment: That's gonna be tough, as I will have to change at every controller that I have retrieved my user model.